# Creating duplicate instances of objects for timeline functionality

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, database, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC based project, in which I would like to add Timeline functionality. The most important object in our project is the `Note`, there are objects associated with it like `NoteHistory` `Attachments`, etc.

Timline functionality here means where Users can scroll through Time in the front-end and objects from that time-period will be loaded in the front-end. Whether they should be `Read-Only` if in past, is another one of my question.

Now, for database, we are using PostgreSQL, and backend in Java8.

For the time-line functionality, what I thought was to create a new entry in DB every night for `Note` and its subsequent objects which are altered. The non-edited objects will remain the same, until they are modified to save disk/database space.

Everytime when a request is made to load a data-set, the corresponding date and time is also passed and that specific data-set is loaded.

When the user wishes to scroll, then again the date & time params are passed, and the data-set is loaded.

How does this technique for Timeline sounds? I am planning to do this all database way. I am interested in knowing if there is any other way to proceed with this problem, a more optimal way.